# Python Django : creating an custom model and displaying it in html

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to python and django. I have seen some tutorials and created a user registration form:

## models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.db import models


class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^register_process/', register_process),
```

## views.py

```
def register_user(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

## register.html

```
{{ form }}
```

The above code works perfectly.

But I did something on my own and it failed:

## models.py

```
class CustomForm(models.Model):

    USER_ID = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    USER_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    PASSWORD = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    class Meta:
        fields = "USER_ID"
        db_table = 'CUSTOM_FORM'
```

## urls.py

```
url(r'^register_process/', register_process),
```

## views.py

```
def register_user(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = CustomForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

## register.html

```
{{ form }}
```

Should I do something extra in models.py?

Comment: In your models.py, you have CustomForm derived from models.Model; do you have a form derived from this model?

Comment: @mike : No i didnt . How to do that ?? Can't we be able to derive an form element and display in an html without importing forms and such things ?? I want everything to be userdefined

Comment: If you look at the MyRegistrationForm class from the tutorial, there is a meta class, which (among other things) defines the model the form is linked to. Your form will also need a model.

Comment: Or, if you're hoping to just have a stand-alone form, change the base class for `CustomForm` to `forms.Form` (you'll need to change the import as well)

Comment: TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): fields,model i get this if i define an model into meta Clas

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? It will need a different solution to display a form and save data to the database or to display a form on its own.

Comment: I want to design an user registration form without the predefined things such as from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm . I want everything to be unique in project . Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Yes. forms.Form works :) But i am unable to save the form using     form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

Comment: It seems that you are mixing Models and Forms. ``CustomForm`` inherits from models.Model so it’s a model and not a form. You should use a ModelForm. Besides, using capitalized attributes is very wrong practice.

Comment: Yes seems ModelForm are the ones that am looking for , I have read the docs. I will try using that . Anysuggesions for learning django other than django book and djangoproject.com ???. It hard to find tutorials on django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to sum up the various comments into an answer.

In the code you posted, models.py has a class named `CustomForm` that is derived from `models.Model`.

In views.py, you're instantiating an instance `CustomForm` and using that instance as an argument to `render_to_response`.

It looks like you're mixing up Models and Forms.

A Model represents a table in a database; a Form is used to get user input.

So, I think you need to change your code in models.py:

```
class MyUserModel(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

Then, add a Form class (in a new module):

```
class MyUserForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUserModel

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

And, in views.py:

```
def register_user(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = MyUserForm()

    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

Personally, I found the tutorials on the Django project site very helpful. I would also question the wisdom of trying to re-implement user registration/authentication when it is something that Django has already! That may be a whole new Question, though.

In case you haven't already seen it, the tutorial can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/).